# Magento2 Custom api with Two methods

Tags: custom, rest-api, methods

I followed below link to create custom api.
https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-api-in-magento-2.html.

Where 2 methods are written in that first method is working but calling 
rest/V1/test1 is showing error like Request does not match any route.

can anyone suggest where is wrong.

Comment: you should specify `customer_id` on calling a request 
`/V1/test1/:param`, `V1/test1/{customer_id}`

Comment: @magefms, I got the solution for it, thanks. If you can help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260079/multiselect-attribute-not-saving-in-magento-2-3-0/

Comment: great. okay I will check

Comment: can you try changing the type from text to `varchar`

Comment: @magefms, ok I will try it, need to change version and upgrade after that?

Comment: if you can do direct from your database , please direct (since it's only for testing)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89116/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-magefms).

Comment: @magefms, no after changing to varchar also, same issue